# why does my code print this <function triangle_area at 0x7f82fa32c710> the perimeter of the triangle s<function triangle_perimeter at 0x7f82fa32c830>

Tags: python

```
def triangle_area(base, height):
    # This function should receive the base and height of a triangle as integers and return the area as a float.
    area = base * height // 2
    return triangle_area

def triangle_perimeter(a,b,c):
    # This function should return the perimeter when 3 sides are provided.
    perimeter = round(a+b+c)
    return triangle_perimeter

def main():
    base = int(input('Enter the base of the triangle: '))
    height = int(input('Enter the height of the triangle: '))
    second = int(input('enter the second of the triangle: '))
    third = int(input('Enter the third of the triangle: '))
    print('the area of the triangle is: ' ,triangle_area)
    print('the perimeter of the triangle is: ', triangle_perimeter)
```

I'm stuck and need answers quickly. if anyone can help me this would be great. Thank you. any input is very helpful or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should give parameters like this:

```
print('the area of the triangle is: ' ,triangle_area(base, height))
print('the perimeter of the triangle is: ', triangle_perimeter(base, second, third))
```

Comment: Thank you. i just tried and it says that it's missing  triangle_area() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Comment: In `triangle_area` function, return `area` not `triange_area`and call the function with parameters like `triangle_area(base, height)` not `triange_area()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes made:-**

```
(1) change your return statement `triangle_area` to `area`
(2) change your return statement `triangle_perimeter` to `perimeter`
(3) Indentation correction
(4) Function calling in `print` statement
```

**Code:-**

```
def triangle_area(base, height):
    #This function should receive the base and height of a triangle as integers and return the area as a float.
    area = base*height // 2
    return area

def triangle_perimeter(a,b,c):
    #This function should return the perimeter when 3 sides are provided
    perimeter = round(a+b+c)
    return perimeter

base = int(input('Enter the base of the triangle: '))
height = int(input('Enter the height of the triangle: '))
second = int(input('enter the second side of the triangle: '))
third = int(input('Enter the third side of the triangle: '))
print('the area of the triangle is: ' ,triangle_area(base,height))
print('the perimeter of the triangle is: ', triangle_perimeter(base,second,third))
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the base of the triangle: 8
Enter the height of the triangle: 12
enter the second side of the triangle: 4
Enter the third side of the triangle: 6
the area of the triangle is:  48
the perimeter of the triangle is:  18
```